# Hibernate expression language does not work

Tags: spring-mvc, el, hibernate-validator

I am using spring + hibernate validator. I am trying to use ${validatedValue} but it does not work. My core dependencies:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.el</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.4</version>
        </dependency>
```

My field is annotated by @Email with validatedValue provided as EL:

```
    @Column(name = "VALUE_", nullable = false)
    @Email(message = "Specified e-mail address: ${validatedValue} is invalid.")
    private String value;
```

If I provide "thisIsNotEmail" as email validation results me in "Specified e-mail address: $validatedValue is invalid" message not "Specified e-mail address: thisIsNotEmail is invalid". Do anyone has idea why it is not working? I tryed on WindFly10 and Pivotal 3.1 but still no luck to get it work...

I would like to have a result like here: http://www.journaldev.com/3626/hibernate-validator-jsr303-example-tutorial

Comment: the annotation `@Email` from Hibernate Validator uses regexp internally. Have you tried to use something like this:
 `@Pattern(regexp="\\w+([.-]?\\w+)*@\\w+([.-]?\\w+)*(.\\w{2,4})+")` instead?

Comment: I am not sure if You understood me correctly. Please see my updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by changing configuration of messageSource.. I got useCodeAsDefaultMessage to true which should be false:

```
messageSource.setUseCodeAsDefaultMessage(false);
```

Full bean:

```
    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename("i18n/messages");
        messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        messageSource.setUseCodeAsDefaultMessage(false);
        messageSource.setFallbackToSystemLocale(false);
        return messageSource;
    }
```

Comment: Is this a bug? I need both `setUseCodeAsDefaultMessage(true)` and `${validatedValue}`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with the change here:

```
@Email(message = "Specified e-mail address: {validatedValue} is invalid.")
```

The enclosing key name with curly braces should work.

Hope this help.

Comment: It returns me: "Specified e-mail address: validatedValue is invalid.". Is this problem can be related to my DTO? In this case I have a one Contact with @Valid Set<Email> emails; and the value is inside of Email.

Comment: I don't think it can cause that issue. It seem your Message Resource can't be loaded and Hibernate does not recognize it. Have you got this yet?! <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="/WEB-INF/resourceMessages" />
  </bean>

Comment: Yes I have message source which is working correctly with localization. When i set message = "{Email.contractorContactEmail.value}" It will take properly localized message from my properties

Comment: So I guess the syntax should be [Class name or some constraint].[field or key]=[Message value].

Comment: Yes but i would like to parametrize this message equal to rejected value from hibernate. I think it is possible by injecting ${validatedValue} in the message as it is here: http://www.journaldev.com/3626/hibernate-validator-jsr303-example-tutorial . Problem is that it is not working for me...